# Could not get unknown property 'config' for type com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin$GoogleServicesPluginConfig

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, libraries

I'm trying to upgrade my `libraries` from  :

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

and I'm getting below error :

[image]

Comment: did you upgrade gradle as well ?

Comment: I upgraded gradle from 5.4.1 to 5.5, reimported the google service config file from firebase and cleaned the project but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 30):

Updating OneSignal Plugin to `0.12.3` solved the problem for me:

```
buildscript {
    //.......
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.3'
    }
    //....
}
```

Check this: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin/issues/95

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score -9):

I got similar issue and I resolved it by downgrading from 4.3.0 to 4.2.0 and ***sync*** the project from Android Studio

**From**

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

**To**

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Comment: This is not a solution dude what if i want to upgrade my libraries? :(

Comment: this is not solution this is patch

Comment: upgrading classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.3' seems to solve this